# How can i remove the chart label on chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I'm working with chart.js, and i want to remove this label above the chart but i don't know how [See this image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpzYb.jpg)

Comment: RTD: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 options: {
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: false,
            }
        }
    }
```

or disable legend inside options

```
legend: {
               display: true,
```